# Custom the object when syncronizing with Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm using the [Laravel-firebase-sync](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync) package. In their docs they say:

> If you need more control over the data that gets synchronized with
>   Firebase, you can override the `getFirebaseSyncData` of the
>   `SyncsWithFirebase` trait and let it return the array data you want to
>   send to Firebase.

But I can't locate that method. I want to know if someone that has already used this package know a way to custom the object that get syncronized.

Why I want to do this? Well, I'm using Laravel as a backend, so in one model I have `Restaurant`, there I have a field called `min_price_range` that is an `integer` that goes from 1-4. But before I return it I transform it to $-$$$$. So I need to do this before the object gets sync in Firebase. Otherwise the objects won't match between Laravel and Firebase databases (when consumed in mobile client apps).

PD1: I've already test it and it doesn't work. It just sync the hole object (the fields of the `visible` array).

PD2: Yes, I've already opened an issue in the project repository but they seem to response a couple months after.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share the code you've written so far from your `Restaurant` model class, please?

Could you also explain what you mean when you state:

> I have a field called min_price_range that is an integer that goes from 1-4. But before I return it I transform it to $-$$$$

Regarding the trait and method, you could not locate you should be able to find it here: https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync/blob/master/src/Mpociot/Firebase/SyncsWithFirebase.php#L50

The trait would be referenced via the following namespace: `Mpociot\Firebase\SyncsWithFirebase`

So I assume if you wish to override the method you would do something like this in your `Restaurant` model class:

```
<?php

use Mpociot\Firebase\SyncsWithFirebase;

class Restaurant extends Model {

    use SyncsWithFirebase;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFirebaseSyncData()
    {
        /*
            Your array model representation goes here 
            including the `min_price_range` transformation
         */
    }

}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: of course I have found the Trait, what I said is that I couldn't locate that method. It seems weird cause my `SyncWithFirebase.php` file does not contain that method. Must be a version thing. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Did you click the link in my answer? It's a direct link to line number where you can find the method `getFirebaseSyncData` that is within the `SyncsWithFirebase` trait. It doesn't really matter if you can find it or not, you need to override the method by reimplementing it in your `Restaurant` model class - did you try this yet? See my answer for an example. Perhaps you could share your `Restaurant` model code as I asked previously and the other questions I asked in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I just realised you awarded the bounty, I guess you fixed it?